# string partitions such that partitions are in increasing order

Tags: algorithm

A string of digits is given, for example, `"12335457"`. A valid partition is a partition of the string such that each segment is strictly greater than that previous segment.

For example, `"12 | 33 | 54 | 57"` is a valid partition and `57 > 54 > 33 > 12`. Another valid partition can be `"12 | 335 | 457"` .

How many valid partitions possible for the given string? The maximum length of the string can be `5000`.

If we use dynamic programming with parameter `i` and `j`, which means, the last segment was from `i ... to ..j`, then we can recurse on the remaining part.

```
int solve(int i,int j) {
    // memoization need to be added
    int last_length = j - i + 1;
    int ans = 0;
    for(int k = j + last_length ; k < n ; k++) {
        if( segment(j+1,k) > segment(i,j) ) {   // this is possible in O(1) even if segment lengths are equal
                                                // we should do some pre preocessing on the given string
                                                // which can take O(n^2) time
                                                // if segment(j+1,k) length is more than L , then it is trivial
            ans += solve(j+1 , k);
        }
    }
}
```

But this approach will take O(n^3) time. How can we reduce it from O(n^3)?

Thank You

Comment: Any constraints?

Comment: I mean constraint is in time. `O(n^3)` will not pass. Max `n` is `5000` where n is the length of the given string.

Comment: Can the substring start with `0`, ie `0047`?

Comment: @PhamTrung In the question digits are only positive.

Answer (score 1):

Observation:

- Let call the min `index` that `segment(j + 1 , index) > segment(i, j)` is `x`, we can see that `solve(i, j) = sum( solve(j + 1, k) ) with x <= k < n`
- so, let call `dp[i][j] = sum(solve[i][k]) with j <= k < n`, we have our function:

  ```
  int solve(int i,int j) {
    // memoization need to be added
    int last_length = j - i + 1;
    int ans = 0;
    int index = getMinIndexForSegment(i,j)
    ans = solve(j + 1, index) + solve(i, j + 1);
    return ans;
  }
  ```
- The last problem is how to calculate `getMinIndexForSegment`? we realise that we can use binary search to quickly find its result.

  ```
  int  getMinIndexForSegment (int i, int j){
     int st = j + 1;
     int ed = n - 1;
     int res = n;
     while(st <= ed){
        int mid = (st + ed)/2;
        if(segment(i, j) < seg(j + 1, mid)){
           res = mid;
           ed = mid - 1;
        }else{
           st = mid + 1;
        }

     }
     return res;
  }
  ```

As mentioned by the OP, if the digit only contains positive number, so we only need to compare two segments `(i , j)` with `(j + 1 , k)` with `k - j - 1 = j - i`

Comment: Isn't "min index" one of two choices? Either the index describing a segment of the same length as `[i, j]` or describing a segment of the same length as `[i, j]` plus 1?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I don't get your question :(

Comment: You defined `index` as `min index where segment(j + 1 , index) > segment(i, j)` but then clearly `index` either makes `segment(j+1, index)` exactly the same length as `segment(i, j)` or that length plus 1 if that segment's number is equal or smaller than `segment(i, j)`. So why would binary search be needed? (a number with one more digit is always greater (assuming no leading zeros.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, good point! The only thing that make me hesitate to do that is because if the substring allows to start by zero, ie `0047` vs `342`, so the binary search is still necessary. Not mentioned in the question so my assumption is it is allowed, I am clarifying it with OP :)

Answer (score 1):

We can have an `O(n^2)` algorithm. Let `f(i, j, s)` represent the number of valid partitions up to the segment ending at the `i`th character of string `s` and extending back `j` characters. Then:

```py
f(i, j, s):
  # A segment extending all the way to the start
  if i + 1 == j:
    return 1

  # A one-character segment that's smaller
  # than the preceding character
  if j == 1 and s[i] <= s[i - 1]:
    return 0

  segment = s[i - j + 1...i]

  # Find longest preceding segment in O(1)
  longest = 
    a segment of length j extending back
    from s[i - j] or length (j-1) if the first
    segment was equal or larger than segment

  # Replace 'sum' with O(1) prefix sum calculation
  # since we can record that for each previous i
  # as we increase j
  return sum(f(i - j, k, s) for k = 1 to length(longest))
```